# Equality of the following two sets

Tags: elementary-number-theory, elementary-set-theory

At page 78 of the book Number Theory by Silverman it is supposed (without proof) that the following two sets are same:

[image]

For $\subset$, if $a$ is such that $\gcd(a,mn)=1$ then $\gcd(a \mod m,m)=1$ and $\gcd(a \mod n,n)=1$; so there exist $b$ and $c$ in the left-hand-side set such that $b=a \mod m$ and $c=a \mod n$ for any element $a$ from the right-hand-side set. But after a long effort I still can't prove the $\superset$ part, i.e. for any $1 \le b \le m$, $\gcd(b,m)=1$ there exists an $1 \le a \le mn$, $\gcd(a,mn)=1$ such that $b=a \mod m$ (and likwise for $c$). Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Stricly speaking, the sets are not the same, there is a bijection between them.

This is only true if $\gcd(m,n)=1$. As a counterexample, take $m=6,\,n=9,\,b=1,\,c=5$. The congruences:
$$\begin{aligned}
a &\equiv 1 \pmod{6}\\
a &\equiv 5 \pmod{9}
\end{aligned}
$$
can have no common solution, since they are not compatible $\pmod{3}$.

If we add that condition, we can solve the congruences:
$$\begin{aligned}
a &\equiv b \pmod{m}\\
a &\equiv c \pmod{m}
\end{aligned}
$$
in the following way.

Since $\gcd(m,n)=1$, there exist integers $u$ and $v$ such that $um +nv = 1$.

Let us take $a=c(um)+b(nv)$. Since $nv\equiv 1\pmod{m}$, we have:
$$ a \equiv (cu)m + b\cdot 1 \equiv b \pmod{m}$$

and you can prove $a\equiv c \pmod{n}$ in a similar way.

This is known as the Chinese Remainder Theorem. See, for example:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem

The theorem does not require that $\gcd(a,mn)=gcd(b,m)=gcd(c,n) = 1$ (although it does require that $gcd(m,n)=1$).

This is a particular case of the theorem; it is true because $gcd(a,mn) \Leftrightarrow gcd(a,m)=gcd(a,n) = 1$.